# Reading from a handle obtained outside createProcess

Tags: haskell, io, ipc

I'm trying to create a process, and communicate with it via a handle that I provide outside the `createProcess` function:

```
stdOutH <- openFile (logDir </> "stdout.log") ReadWriteMode
hSetBuffering stdOutH LineBuffering
(_, _, _, ph) <- createProcess $
    (proc "someproc" []) { std_out = UseHandle stdOutH
                         , std_err = UseHandle stdErrH
                         }
line <- hGetLine stdOutH
putStrLn $ "Got " ++ line
```

The `"someproc"` process spits a line out to the standard output, and I want to read it from the process that spawned it. However if I try to do this I get the following error:

hGetLine: illegal operation (handle is closed)

What I don't understand is why the handle is closed while the created process is running. This works if I use `CreatePipe` instead of `UseHandle`, the problem is that I only want to read the first line. But doing this requires to keep on reading from the pipe, otherwise it gets full after a certain amount of output by `"someproc"`.

So, is there a way to use `system.process` to communicate two processes via `stdOutH` in the way described above?

Comment: For clearing a pipe you don't intend to use again, you can use `forkIO (forever (hGetChar pipeHandle))`.

Comment: That's more or less what I ended up doing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior of `createProcess` is [documented](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.2.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:createProcess):

> Note that Handles provided for std_in, std_out, or std_err via the
>   UseHandle constructor will be closed by calling this function.

Documentation suggests to use `createProcess_` function instead.

Comment: I should have read better :/ Anyways, I think I cannot use a file handle anyway, since I need to have "blocking reads" which wait for output of the spawned process, and this requires a pipe (instead of a file)...