# Reading a couple of lines of a pipe obtained with createProcess and then closing it

Tags: haskell, process, io, ipc

I have a function that spawns a process as follows:

```
(_, Just outh, _, ph) <- createProcess $
    (proc "someproc" []) { std_out = CreatePipe }
line <- hGetLine outh
doSomeComputationOn line
-- ... 'outh' is not read anymore from here onwards
```

So `"someproc"` is created, and then the parent reads a `line` from it to obtain some information, and then it forgets about the pipe whose handle is `outh`.

Now the problem is that if the pipe is not read, `"someproc"` will block as soon as it is full. So this requires that the parent process reads `outh` even if it does not do anything with it. So my questions are:

1. Is this this a good way to get the first line of a child process' output and then forget about additional output?
2. Is there any way in Haskell in which I can automatically discard the input to the pipe (or even redirect it to a file)?.

So far the only way I can see to woraround this problem is spawning a new thread that constantly tries to read from `outh` (and just discards the output), which indicates that I'm doing something wrong ...

As additional background, this question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47053799/reading-from-a-handle-obtained-outside-createprocess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now the problem is that if the pipe is not read, "someproc" will block as soon as it is full.  [...] Is there any way in Haskell in which I can automatically discard the
>   input to the pipe (or even redirect it to a file)?

There is a helper library for *process* called [*process-streaming*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-streaming) (written by the author of this answer) that tries to do just that: even if the user passes a stream-consuming function that doesn't exhaust a standard stream, it drains the stream *automatically* under the hood to avoid potential deadlocks.

The library doesn't work directly with handles, but accepts [pipe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes)-consuming functions and [foldl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl) folds through an [adapter type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-transduce-0.4/docs/Pipes-Transduce.html).

An example of reading the first line:

```
import           Data.Text.Lazy
import qualified Pipes.Prelude
import           System.Process.Streaming      (CreateProcess,shell,
                                                piped,execute,foldOut,transduce1,withCont)
import           System.Process.Streaming.Text (utf8x,foldedLines)

program :: CreateProcess
program = piped $ shell "{ echo aaa ; echo bbbb ; }"

firstLine :: IO (Maybe Text)
firstLine = execute program streams
    where
    streams = foldOut
            . transduce1 utf8x
            . transduce1 foldedLines
            $ withCont Pipes.Prelude.head
```

The library has a much bigger dependency footprint than *process* though.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to use depends on the behavior of the external command.

If you simply want to interrupt that, you can `hClose outh`. This will close the pipe, and further writes to the pipe by the external command will fail with a "broken pipe" error. Most processes terminate upon receiving this.

If you instead want to read and discard the output, you can do that as well. Perhaps the easiest way is

```
do c <- hGetContents outh
   evaluate (length c)  -- force this to fetch all data
   doStuff              -- now we are sure that the remote end closed its output
```

which should run in constant space.

If you don't want to wait for the process to end before performing `doStuff`, wrap everything in `forkIO`.

Comment: Won't this also cause and "end of file" error, as soon as `doStuff` tries to read from `outh` before the spawned process produces something?

Comment: @DamianNadales `doStuff` must never read from `outh` -- the point of the code above it is to read all from `outh` and discard it.

Comment: That's the problem, that I need to read only one line, and then discard the rest :) Otherwise I could redirect it to a file.

Comment: @DamianNadales What's the issue, then? First read a line with `getLine`, and later use the code above to discard the rest.

Comment: The problem is that if I try to read before the process has written something the parent process won't block but receive an end of file error.